# Запрет поворота экрана только на телефонах (не на планшетах) android

Tags: java, android, activity

Нужно запретить поворот экрана одной активити на телефонах, а на планшетах оставить. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `res/values-sw600dp`, `res/values-large` и `res/values-sw720dp-land` создаёте файл `bool.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

(В `res/values` тот же файл, но с `<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>`)

Теперь можете в коде получать значение "планшет/телефон" так:

```
boolean isTablet = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
```

И теперь есть варианты:

1. Запускать активити с прописанным в манифесте запретом на поворот (разрешением  быть только в одном режиме).

   ```
   <activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
   ```
2. Программно запрещать поворот активити. Например [так](https://github.com/mohaxspb/Odnako/blob/master/src/ru/kuchanov/odnako/LockOrientation.java):

   ```
   switch (act.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)
   {
       case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
           {
               act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
           }
           else
           {
               int rotation = act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
               if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_180)
               {
                   act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
               }
               else
               {
                   act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
               }
           }
       break;

       case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
           {
               act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
           }
           else
           {
               int rotation = act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
               if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90)
               {
                   act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
               }
               else
               {
                   act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
               }
           }
       break;
   }
   ```