# Ориентация экрана на телефонах и планшетах

Tags: java, android, orientation

Можно ли настроить ориентацию экрана по разному: на телефонах запретить горизонтальную, а оставить принудительно только вертикальную, а на планшетах разрешить и горизонтальную и вертикальную? Как это сделать?

Comment: До вызова `setContentView()` проверить размер экрана и, если он меньше планшетного принудительно установить портретный режим: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: Дубль: [Запрет поворота экрана только на телефонах (не на планшетах) android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468500/11515) и ещё вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593764/11515

Answer (score 1):

Да можно. Надо завести отдельные ресурсы для разных разрешений:

```
res/layout/my_activity.xml           # для аппаратов шириной менее 800dp 
res/layout-sw800dp/my_activity.xml   # для планшетов шириной более 800dp
```

[документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Comment: Вопрос о другом, кмк.